# Unable to create foreign key constraint in MySQL. Error number 150

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench

I am attempting to create a data model. It's fairly complicated, but I'm trying to link the Splits table to the Trials table. A screenshot of the model is below:

[image]

I'm attempting to make Splits.protocol + Splits.resultID + Splits.trialNumber a foreign key to Trials. Those three relations are the primary key of Trials. I'm doing this with MySQL Workbench and it throws an Error #150. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Here is the SQL statement and the error that it throws when attempting to execute it:

```
ERROR 1005: Can't create table '403898_BAMNormalized.#sql-7285_6c29081' (errno: 150)

SQL Statement:

ALTER TABLE `403898_BAMNormalized`.`Splits` 

ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_FromTrial`
    FOREIGN KEY (`protocol` , `resultID` , `trialNumber`)
    REFERENCES `403898_BAMNormalized`.`Trials` (`protocol` , `resultID` , `trialNumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 1050: Table 'Splits' already exists

SQL Statement:

CREATE TABLE `Splits` (
    `protocol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `resultID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `trialNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `splitNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `splitScore` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`protocol`,`resultID`,`trialNumber`,`splitNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Here are the create table statements:

```
CREATE TABLE `Trials` (
    `resultID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `protocol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `trialNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `trialScore` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
    `best` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `DQFlag` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`resultID`,`protocol`,`trialNumber`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_trialID` FOREIGN KEY (`resultID`, `protocol`) REFERENCES `ResultsDetails` (`resultID`, `protocol`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Splits` (
    `protocol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `resultID` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `trialNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `splitNumber` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `splitScore` decimal(10,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`protocol`,`resultID`,`trialNumber`,`splitNumber`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Indexes of Trials table:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide SQL code of the two tables and the FK definition which fails?

Comment: Added some stuff. Does that help? Is there anything else that might help?

Comment: Please provide the `create table` statement of Trials. Please also use the code indention mechanism which is provided by stack overflow. The current code is very hard to read.

Comment: Added! Is there anything else that I can provide?

Comment: Add an index over `("protocol" , "resultID" , "trialNumber")` to the table `trials`. Should work then.

Comment: I think I already have that. I just went into the indexes for trials. Here's a screenshot of that tab added to the original post.

Comment: Please avoid screenshots and provide SQL queries instead. Please also try to supply all relevant queries (create table sure should include all create index statements as well ;) ). Most likely ordering is relevant. Your screenshot shows `("resultID", "protocol", "trialNumber")` while your FK references `("protocol", "resultID", "trialNumber")`. Give it a try and reorder one of those.

Comment: Ah the ordering was the issue. Switched it and it worked immediately. Thanks! Shall I post that as an answer, or would you like to so I can give you credit?

Comment: Please post the output of [`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-innodb-status.html) **immediately** after attempting to create this FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reordering the index to represent the same order as the foreign key was the solution. See comments appended to original post for detailed information.